Logitech Mx keys mini connecting only when pairing, afterwards any subsequent connections fail in Ubuntu 24.04
I am able to pair the keyboard through bluetoothctl, even though I have to run 2-3 times pair [MAC] it works.
The problem that I have is after I turn the bluetooth off and on or I reboot my system it cannot connect again, only if I unpair it and pair it again.
The system sees the keyboard but it goes through a cycle of connecting on/off and it seems to be in line with the little light indicator of the easy-switch.
The error that seems that I am getting is this: Attempting to connect to D6:14:00:2A:7D:6E Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed le-connection-abort-by-local
Looks something like this:

